# "naku" suffix and "o" prefix? 保存をお忘れなくですぞ

Tags: syntax

> 保存をお忘れなくですぞ！

I am guessing the word "naku" is a suffix meaning not? So then it'd be saying, "do not forget to save!"? And is the "o" before "wasure" there to make it more polite?

Comment: 御～なく is a somewhat common pattern, e.g. お構いなく, ご心配なく, etc. See also [this question](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14944/3437).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

お忘れなく means 忘れずに or 忘れないで, *don't forget*. It's the negative form of an honorific form of 忘れる. Here is the definition of お/ご～ある/ない in the dictionary:

> [ある](http://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%9C%89%E3%82%8B) 動詞の連用形や動作性の漢語名詞などに付いて、多く「お…ある」「御(ご)…ある」の形で、その動作をする人に対する尊敬を表す。「おいで―・れ」「御笑覧―・れ」

More examples:

> お忘れなく -> 忘れないで
> お構いなく -> 構わないで
> ご遠慮なく -> 遠慮しないで
> ご心配なく -> 心配しないで
> お咎めなく -> 咎めないで
> お見逃しなく -> 見逃さないで

Normally, you don't put です after なく, and ですぞ sounds somewhat archaic.

I presume ending every sentence with ですぞ is the speaker's [idiosyncrasy](http://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%9E).

Comment: Oh I see, ok it must be using desu after naku because this is very formal text.

Comment: @Ash, I mean なくです is almost ungrammatical, and ですぞ does not sound formal. I think the author is trying to achieve some dramatic effect.