# 「仕方なくです」 形容詞の連用形 く+ copula です?

Tags: adjectives, i-adjectives, copula

I am stumped by 「仕方なくです」 which I have heard/seen occasionally.

> 用があり仕方なく広島へ。。。仕方なくですね ([source](https://beauty.hotpepper.jp/slnH000160839/blog/bidA043636216.html))

> 一年ぶりに来ました。友人に行きたいと言われて仕方なくですが、、、鶏皮は一人5本に減ってました。([source](https://www.google.com/maps/contrib/117540407496366990109/place/ChIJVVVRgJaRQTUR3I8lPBq6YVs/@33.5892153,130.4081892,17z/data=!3m1!4b1))

> 仕方なくです！(笑) ([source](https://satojuku-sato.com/nichijyo-577/))

I know 形容詞の連用形 く, apart from its usage preceding 体言, is also used in 中止法. But why can it occur before the copula/polite marker です? Is this something of a fixed expression for comical effect? Can other words/expressions be used this way? Might it be a similar case to [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17446)?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/85826/5010 /  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/58949/5010

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can regard them as cleft sentences for additional information.

Take the first sentence (with a little change/simplification) for example.

- 用があり広島へ行きました。 I went to Hiroshima for an engagement.

Then

- 仕方なくですね.

can be unfolded as

- （私が広島へ行ったのは）**仕方なく**ですね。 It was because I had no choice (that I went to Hiroshima).

---

In terms of 'sentences pattern', the following are the same.

- 昨日彼女に会いました。たまたまです。I met her yesterday. (It was) Just by chance.
- たまたま彼女に会いました。昨日（のこと）です。 I met her by chance. (And it was) Yesterday.

---

**[Edit] 仕方なくです/仕方ないです**

When the subject is *I*, these are not very different.

- 私は広島へ行きました。仕方なくですね/仕方ないですね。

Both essentially mean *I had to go to Hiroshima*. Grammatically, 仕方なく (implicitly) modifies 行きました while 仕方ない refers to the fact that the speaker went to Hiroshima.

On the other hand, when the subject is not first person:

- 彼は広島へ行きました。仕方なくですね/仕方ないですね。

Here 仕方なくですね means that he had no choice but to go. 仕方ないですね indicates the speaker's feeling towards his going to Hiroshima (In effect, *There is nothing I can do about his going*. Depending on the context, *I understand he had to go* or *I have to do without him* etc.).

Comment: Thank you and +1. But I guess what puzzled me was the difference between 仕方なくです and 仕方ないです, and what nuances 連用形 imparts here.

Comment: @EddieKal Pls see the edit.