# What form of imperative is this? 是非この機会お見逃しなく！

Tags: negation, imperatives, て-form

The following statement seems like an imperative but does not have  the structure of the imperative:

> 是非{ぜひ}この機会{きかい}お見逃{みのが}し**なく**！ Make sure not to miss this opportunity!

1. Is **なく** 連用形 of **ない**? If yes, how can a sentence end on 連用形?
2. Is **て** implied after **なく**?

Comment: Related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/14944/5010

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 「お/ご + Verb in 連用形{れんようけい} (continuative form) + なく 」

should be learned as a set phrase meaning "***Please do not (verb).***"  The grammar used here is sort of special.  One might say a phrase like 「お願{ねが}いいたします」 is implied or left unsaid at the end.

This is an **honorific form of a polite request rather than a plain imperative**.  The honorific お/ご at the beginning alone should already suggest that.

If you translated 「お見逃しなく」 into "**Don't miss it!**" (, which is a reasonable translation) , it might look like an imperative.  However, it is just the translation that is an imperative, not the original Japanese.  "Don't miss it!" is not honorific speech by any standard, is it?

Comment: The word before なく is actually a noun (or [a noun formed from the verb-stem](http://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/32311/5010)), which can be confirmed by expressions like ご心配なく, どうぞご遠慮なく.